# De qué manera podría contar la cantidad de veces que el signo + se repite en un dato String

Tags: java, android

Tengo un String en donde guardo una cadena de números con un signo + antes del número. Lo que quiero es poder contar cuántos signos + existen, para poder saber así la cantidad de números y signos que hay en la cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```
String cadenanumeros = "+0+4+3+4+5";

Signos+ = 5;
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay al menos 7 formas de hacer esto con código propio de Java, aparte de algunas soluciones basadas en librerías y aportadas en otras respuestas.

Te muestro aquí esas 7 formas con Java puro:

Definiremos nuestra cadena de prueba:

```
    String testString = "+0+4+3+4+5";
```

#### 1. con `replace`:

```
    int replace = testString.length() - testString.replace("+", "").length();
    System.out.println("1. Con replace = " + replace);
```

#### 2. Con `replaceAll`:

```
    int replaceAll = testString.replaceAll("[^+]", "").length();
    System.out.println("2. Con replaceAll = " + replaceAll);
```

#### 3. Con `replaceAll`(2º caso):

```
    int replaceAllCase2 = testString.length() - testString.replaceAll("\\+", "").length();
    System.out.println("3. Con replaceAll (2º caso) = " + replaceAllCase2);
```

#### 4. Con `split`:

```
    int split = testString.split("\\+",-1).length-1;
    System.out.println("4. Con split = " + split);
```

#### 5. Con expresiones lambda (a partir de Java 8):

```
    long java8 = testString.chars().filter(ch -> ch =='+').count();
    System.out.println("5. Con Lambda (Java8) = " + java8);
```

#### 6. Con expresiones lambda (2º caso):

```
    long java8Case2 = testString.codePoints().filter(ch -> ch =='+').count();
    System.out.println("6. Con Lambda (2º caso) = " + java8Case2);
```

#### 7. Con `stringTokenizer`:

```
    int stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(" " +testString + " ", "+").countTokens()-1;
    System.out.println("7. Con stringTokenizer = " + stringTokenizer);
```

---

#### Salida:

```
1. Con replace = 5
2. Con replaceAll = 5
3. Con replaceAll (2º caso) = 5
4. Con split = 5
5. Con Lambda (Java8) = 5
6. Con Lambda (2º caso) = 5
7. Con stringTokenizer = 5
```

---

#### Demo

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/MGKIW58685)**</kbd>

---

#### Fuente

La [respuesta con mayor acogida](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string/35242882#35242882) a la pregunta *[Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)*  en Stackoverflow en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Contar número de veces que aparece un carácter

```
int number = CharMatcher.is('+').countIn(cadenanumeros);
```

Original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764170/5675636).

Otra opción

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("a.b.c.d", ".");
```

Original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816989/5675636).

Comment: Cómo se implementa el CharMatcher o el StringUtils? Ambos me aparecen como "cannot resolve the method"

Comment: ChartMatcher pertenece a Guava, que son librerías de Google que te permiten simplificar el proceso, te dejo un enlace [http://www.baeldung.com/category/guava/]

Comment: Si, había ido a ese enlace pero está roto, no encuentro el código para implementarlo :/

Comment: Si, el primero esta roto, te he puesto uno diferente

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma es usando un `for` loop y que cuente todos los "+"
que contiene ese string:

```
String cadenanumeros = "+0+4+3+4+5";
char equisChar = '+';   // el caracter que vas a contar
int cuantos = 0;        // inicializas el int

    for (int i = 0; i < cadenanumeros.length(); i++) {
    if (cadenanumeros.charAt(i) == equisChar) {
    cuantos++;
        }
    }
    Log.i("CUANTOS + ", String.valueOf(cuantos));
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto deberia funcionar

```
  String cadenanumeros = "+0+4+3+4+5";
    int cantidad = cadenanumeros.replaceAll("[^+]", "").length();
    Log.e("Cantidad:",""+cantidad);
```

te va a reemplazar todos los + que tengas ahi y va a contar la cantidad

Otra forma podria ser la siguiente, restar al tamaño total del string menos el tamaño sacando los + , esto te devuelve la cantidad de signos + en ese string

```
int cantidad = cadenanumeros.length() - cadenanumeros.replace(".", "").length();
```

Esta opcion de arriba es mucho mas rapida y mejor por que no usa regex para sacar la cantidad de + de ese string